# domain of the pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine the  domain of the  pointwise   convergence of $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left (\frac{1+x}{x} \right)^n$ ?

## My attempt :

$-1 < \frac{1}{n} \left (\frac{1+x}{x} \right)^n < 1$

$-1 <  \left (\frac{1+x}{x} \right) < 1$

$-2 <  \left (\frac{1}{x} \right) < 0$

$-\infty <  {x}  < -2$

So  the  domain of the point convergence of $S$ is $( -\infty , -2)$

Is  its true ?

Comment: The last step is wrong: $-2 < \frac{1}{x} < 0$ if and only if $-\infty < x < -1/2$. Also, note that the first two inequalities are not equivalent except for $n = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the series does not converge when $\left| \frac{1 + x}{x} \right| > 1$ because the general term is not infinitesimal. This happens when $\left| 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right| > 1$, i.e., when $x > -1/2$. When $x = -1/2$ the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges. When $x < -1/2$ the series converges absolutely for every $x$ (in particular pointwise) by comparison with a geometric series of ratio $\left| \frac{1+x}{x} \right| < 1$.

Comment: For completeness, you should probably add a few words explaining why $|y| < 1$ implies that $\sum \frac{1}{n} y^n$ converges (e.g. ratio test).